# panel autoscroll turns off when switching between windows

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I created an interface it has several forms you can switch between using a panel as the parent form. My problem is that when i switch between my forms on the second time i open a form if that form has autoscroll on a panel it will not allow you to scroll and the window is stuck on the view you previously had.

In this image i open the form internet. after doing so i will click on instruction( any form switch triggers this)

[image]

now i open the same form again and the scroll bar is gone and it locks in on the last position the form was in.

[image]

the very curious thing in this is that this only happens on the internet form word also has a scroll bar however even though the properties and settings for both are identical only one does not work.
What could be causing this and how do i go about troubleshooting errors like this.

*The forms are removed from the panel and re-added, they are not closed.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Assumption 0:

> The forms are removed from the panel and re-added, they are not
>   closed.

Store the state of panel autoscroll and set it after you have re-added it. Note that if you add controls to the panel first and panel is not docked, then scroll will not appear because panel dimensions can be huge. You should set following property as well:

```
vScrollBar1.Vericalscroll.Value = 0
```

### Assumption 1:

I assume what is actually going on is that you do not add controls to that panel, but to the form behind it or something similar. In that case - program is correct, you just asked it to do a wrong thing.

### Assumption 2:

Assuming is panel is anchored top, left, bottom, right. There is currently a limitation in Windows Forms that prevents all classes derived from ScrollableControl from acting properly when both RightToLeft is enabled and AutoScroll is set to True.

Manual : [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll.aspx)

### Assumption 3:

You add the controls back, by recreating them, but forget to add handlers or create them in order where scrollbar is out of view. Instead of absolute positions you could use dockstyle:

```
Dim vScrollBar1 As VScrollBar = New VScrollBar
vScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Right
Controls.Add(vScrollBar1)
```

Comment: while it is not ancored it is also not docked theo objects that i add to the panel are or rather is the form the all work two use scroll dude to the size the word and the internet so they are set to auto scroll  so after reading your answers i tried setting auto scroll on the panel which fixed my problem except one thing which is that two scroll bars appear one for the horizontal plain and one for the vertical scroll-bar

Comment: Have you tried : **vScrollBar1.HorizontalScroll.Visible = False**